# Two-factor authentication on Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, security, authentication

Is there a way to enable two-factor authentication to access my Ubuntu One account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two factor authentication is still in beta, but you can follow the FAQ at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSO/FAQs/2FA to request access to the beta.

This will allow you to enable the two factor requirement to access all web sites, but some client code does not support two factor yet.

Comment: Is this feature still in beta? In the year 2021?